# What is wrong with this while-loop (C++)?

Tags: c++

I was pretty sure I was doing this the right way, but apparently I'm not. This while loops keeps running infinitely once it reaches 0. It keeps outputting "Monthly Payment: $0.00" and "Your loan after that payment is: $0.00" over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

```
while (loan_balance ! = 0)
  {
    monthly_payment = loan_balance / 20;
    loan_balance = loan_balance - monthly_payment;

    cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << monthly_payment << ends;
    cout << "Your loan balance after that payment is: $" << loan_balance << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger? Is `monthly_payment` ever `0`, if so you will not change `loan_balance`

Comment: what variable types are `loan_balance` and `monthly_payment`?

Comment: @NoamHacker They are both type double.

Comment: I think you should read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Does the original code really have a space between the `!` and the `=`?  `!=` is a single token, and a space isn't allowed.

Comment: Even if `loan_balance` and `monthly_payment` are not floating point types, if `monthly_payment` ever becomes `0`, then you'll end up with an infinite loop.  And it's very easy for `monthly_payment` to become `0` since **integral division is rounded down**; if `loan_balance` is an integer type, and ever takes a value less than `20`, `loan_balance / 20` will be `0`.

Comment: `ends` doesn't make any sense for `cout`.  To be honest, `endl` almost never makes any sense for `cout` (people think it's the platform neutral way to say "newline", but that's `'\n'`; `endl` is the way to say "newline, followed by flushing the stream", and you probably don't care if the stream gets flushed at that moment).

Answer (score 4):

If `load_balance` is a floating point type (`float` or `double`), then `load_balance != 0` (where `0` is `0.0f`) will likely never be false unless it is explicitly set to `load_balance = 0.0f`. So it should be compared to a small threshold instead, e.g.

```
while(load_balance >= 1e-4)
```

Also the not-equal operator is `!=`, with a space `! =` is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

loan_balance is probably a float or double; it might decrease to be something close to but not quite 0.  Change your comparison to "> 0".

Comment: It would still return true, loan_balance would still be a tad above 0, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**0** is  a data type of type `int`

**0.0f** is a data type of type `double` or `float`

So you're saying

```
while(loan_balance != 0)
  do stuff
```

The compiler in return says: "`loan_balance` will never ***ever*** be **0** if it is a double/float, so I'll just keep doing stuff."

Keep in mind: integers aren't floats/doubles

Comment: Right for the wrong reason. You can compare floating point and integer, but you have to know floating point is imprecise, so exact equality is unlikely

Answer (score 0):

Your loan_balance is most likely never actually going to be 0 exactly. I am pretty sure you want your loan_balance in float or double.

```
double loan_balance=23000.00;
while (loan_balance >0.000)
  {
    monthly_payment = loan_balance / 20.0;
    loan_balance = loan_balance - monthly_payment;

    cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << monthly_payment << ends;
    cout << "Your loan balance after that payment is: $" << loan_balance << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're facing a problem with both precision and rounding.

When you exponentially decrease a number, it will converge to zero.  If it is a limited precision floating point number, there will be a number that is so small that cannot be distinguishable from zero with any possible representation.  So, a loop like

```
double d=1.0;  // or some other finite value
while(d!=0.0)
    d*=ratio;  // ratio is some finite value so that fabs(ratio)<1.0
```

would finish in a finite number of iterations.

However, depending on the values of `d` and `ratio`, especially when `d` approaches zero in the subnormal range (implying fewer significant bits) and `fabs(ratio)` is close to 1.0 (slow convergence), the selected rounding mode can cause `d*ratio` to be rounded towards `d`.  When that happens, the loop above will never end.

In machines/compilers that support IEC 60559, you should be able to test and set the floating point rounding mode, using `fegetround()` and `fesetround()` (declared in `<fenv.h>`).  It is likely that the default rounding on your system is to the nearest.  For the loop above to converge more quickly (or at all), it would be better to cause rounding to be toward 0.

Note however, that it comes with a price: depending on the application changing the rounding mode might be undesirable on the grounds of precision/accuracy (OTOH, if your already working in the subnormal range, your precision is probably not that good anymore anyway).

But the original question's convergence problem is still a little bit more complicated, because it is done with a two-step operation.  So there is one rounding in the division operation, and another one in the subtraction.  To increase the chance and speed of convergence, the subtraction should take as much of `loan_balance`'s value as possible, so **maybe** rounding up would be better in this case.  In fact, when I added `fesetround(FP_UPWARD)` to the OP's original code (together with defining the initial value of `loan_balance` to `1.0`), it converged after 14466 iterations.  (**Note however that that is just a guess**, and the effect on the original code might have been just a special condition.  A more in-depth analysis would be necessary to qualify it, and such an analysis would have to take into account different values of ratio, and the relative greatness of minuend and subtrahend.)